# How to set URL for Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, vagrant, maven-3

I have the following error after launch `mvn clean install vagrant:up`:

```
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-api/4.2.0/avalon-framework-api-4.2.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:pom:4.2.0' in repository snapshot-repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
Downloading: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-api/4.2.0/avalon-framework-api-4.2.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:pom:4.2.0' in repository Avalon-repo (http://central.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-api/4.2.0/avalon-framework-api-4.2.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:pom:4.2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-impl/4.2.0/avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:pom:4.2.0' in repository snapshot-repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
Downloading: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-impl/4.2.0/avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:pom:4.2.0' in repository Avalon-repo (http://central.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-impl/4.2.0/avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:pom:4.2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Unable to get dependency information: Error in metadata for artifact 'rubygems:vagrant:gem': Unable to parse version '[0.5.2,0.5.2.0.0.0.0.1)' for dependency 'rubygems:archive-tar-minitar:gem': Range defies version ordering: [0.5.2,0.5.2.0.0.0.0.1)
  rubygems:vagrant:gem:1.0.7

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  rubygems (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases),
  snapshot-repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots),
  Avalon-repo (http://central.maven.org/maven2)

Path to dependency: 
    1) downloader:downloader:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    2) net.ju-n.maven.plugins:vagrant-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0.1
```

I have searched this dependency and I found it in another URL, but I don't know how to set it. I don't want to download the jar manually, because we are using Jenkins and I don't have access to that repository.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks!!

P.S. My `pom.xml` is (partial):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>vagrant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
  <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Update1:** I have the following repositories in my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>      
    <repository>
        <id>snapshot-repository</id>
        <name>Maven2 Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>Avalon-repo</id>
      <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

**Update2:** The problem that Maven is looking for the dependency in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-impl/4.2.0/avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.pom, but the correct URL is: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/avalon-framework/avalon-framework-api/4.2.0/avalon-framework-api-4.2.0.pom

Comment: it seems maven cannot download any artifact. The repositories look fine to me. are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `settings.xm`l under your `.m2` folder. You must add a repository here like below:

```
</repository>
                  <repository>
                      <id>central</id>
                      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
                      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                      <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                      </snapshots>
                    </repository>
```

Comment: Hi @Sezin, I already have added the repository in my pom.xml: `<repository>
      <id>Avalon-repo</id>
      <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>` but the problem persists.

Comment: You can add it to your local repository manually in the worst case

Comment: but if you cant add it to your local repo, probably maven cant also add it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code in pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>appfuse-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse-snapshots</url>    // Replace it with your respective repository
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem where my lookup for dependencies were failing. As it was kind of replacing org.xxx as org/xxx and none of the dependencies were pulled.

The url for default Central Maven repository is http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.
Unless you want to fetch artifacts from different location (like local artifactory etc.,)  Remove  section or you can still have

```
       <repository> 
           <id>central</id>
           <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
       </repository>
```

mvn clean install
it should download all repositories that you are looking for.